Trying to force run `su' in a pty
I have a shell, where I switch to another user with su -l anotheruser, this mostly works
But when there is no pty allocated to su, it errors out with:
su: must be run from a terminal

So, I tried to wrap su with code to create a pty:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pty.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    char* args[] = {"/bin/su", "-l", "anotheruser", NULL };
    char name[16] = {0};
    int pid ;

    pid = forkpty(&fd, name, NULL, NULL);
    if (pid != -1) {
        printf("\n pty: [%s]\n", name);
        if (execve(args[0], args, NULL) == -1) {
            printf("\n execve: failed\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("\n forkpty: failed \n");
    }

    return 0;
}


But this doesn't seem to work..
I am missing something here, but not able to make out.. do I have to
redirect stdin/stdout before execve()?

try adding '--pty' to your command, that will create a pseudo terminal. (see the manpage for full details (too long to post)

Can you switch from su to sudo?

Does your su support the -P / --pty option?  If so, then does it help?

Under what circumstances does this even arise? You're not passing a -c option to su, so you're asking for an interactive session.  Why would you be doing that from a context where you don't already have a terminal?  Are you maybe looking for the setuid() function instead?

You don't need the "su" command. Have your program call setuid() to your intended user, and then system() whatever command you want. After you build the program, change the ownership of the executable to root, move it to a root-owned directory (e.g. /usr/local/bin), and chmod +s file so that when you run it, it will run as root.

@ticktalk the version of su I have does not have --pty :-(
@Barmar No, I have to use su as there are PAM rules to allow passwordless switch to another user for su.
@JohnBollinger I have also tried with -c /bin/bash -- didn't help!
@StreveFord I can't have suid programs - security reasons.

This gave me a good start,  thank you all, I downloaded util-linux sources from github and compiled latest version of su, which has the --pty option. But this version is somehow prompting for password even though I have set ...pam_succeed_if.so user = anotheruser in pam.d/su

am confused, as the forkpty succeeds .. alluding to a pty having been allocated, but you don't show that even  though you've this 'printf("\n pty: [%s]\n", name);' . are you showing EVERYTHING that's output ?

use execvp as it uses environment settings
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pty.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    char* args[] = {"/bin/su", "anotheruser", "-l", "-P", NULL };
    char name[16] = {0};
    int pid ;

    pid = forkpty(&fd, name, NULL, NULL);
    if (pid != -1) {
        printf("\npty:[%s], TERM:%s\n", name, getenv("TERM") );
        if (execvp(args[0], args ) == -1) {
            perror("\nexecvp failed\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("\n forkpty: failed \n");
    }

    return 0;
}


None of these approaches worked, so I built the su from util-linux package and that  worked (even without --pty!). I really appreciate all the help and pointers, I learnt a lot about tty/pty/sshd!! Thank you
